# “Is it any wonder?” reversal

Tags: meaning, idioms

It's my understanding that “Is it any wonder . . . ?” is a rhetorical question used to state the obvious, usually with a degree of sarcasm, equivalent to “It's no wonder that . . .” or “Small wonder that. . . .” For example:

> Is it any wonder that Chris is late to the party?

means roughly:

> Nobody should be surprised that Chris is late to the party.

However, the Styx song [“Too Much Time on My Hands”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Too_Much_Time_on_My_Hands) reverses the usual sense of the idiom:

> Yeah, I'm sittin' on this bar stool talking like a damn fool
>   Got the twelve o'clock news blues
>   And I've given up hope for the afternoon soaps
>   And a bottle of cold brew
>   **Is it any wonder I'm not crazy?**
>   **Is it any wonder I'm sane at all?**
>   . . .
>   **Is it any wonder I'm not a criminal?**
>   **Is it any wonder I'm not in jail?**

Here, the answer to the rhetorical question appears to be “**Yes,** it actually is surprising that I'm not crazy and in jail.” Later in the song, they use the idiom in a more typical fashion, with sarcasm apparent in the singer's tone:

> Is it any wonder I'm not the President?
>   Is it any wonder I'm null and void?

Is the **reversed** sense of this idiom actually widespread, or is this just artistic license by a songwriter?

Comment: Is it any wonder that song lyrics play fast and loose with language?

Comment: Which is why we typically close such questions off topic (lit crit/interpretation request).

Comment: I don't need it interpreted – the meaning is clear. I just want to know if anyone uses it that way in ordinary speech or writing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about song lyrics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the reversed sense of this idiom actually widespread, or is this just artistic license by a songwriter?

It is just artistic license. Once you start playing with poetry and song double meanings and word play quickly break common idioms.

If you wanted to express "Is it any wonder?" non-sarcastically you would say:

> Do you wonder why Chris is late to the party?
>
> I wonder why Chris is late to the party.

Comment: Good point about the alternate phrasing. I wouldn't expect to hear "Do you wonder?" but "I wonder why ..." is definitely more natural than reversing the idiom.